# UITableView not scrolling properly

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have used UITableView in my application. My tableview is not scrolling properly. Earlier it used to be but after some code modification (not in any tableview methods datasource/delegates) its not scrolling freely. Other controls like toolbar buttons, action sheet all are working fine. I have checked my datasource & delegates connection which are proper.

I m not able to figure out what is the issue, same thing also happens on my another view controller.

Comment: Which information you are displaying in tablview?

Comment: only string tht to just of one or two words

Comment: This string comes from parsing??

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Solution : Actually It was my mistake. I had some mutable arrays which were responsible for parsing the data. I have not released them properly. Once I released them properly, my tableview started scrolling perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be if you are making some server operation like connecting, downloading some data while tableview is loading, obviously the tableview jerks while scrolling.

Comment: Yes, I m doing server interaction but once that finishes thn only I m refreshing the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying too many child rows? The `UITableView` scrolling slows down in that case. The best solution then would be to draw your individual rows rather than adding subviews. You can look at [fast scrolling `UITableview`](http://www.therefinedgeek.com.au/index.php/2010/12/21/fast-scrolling-uitableview-updates-for-ios-4-2/) for help.

Comment: No, its not more then 50 currently. earlier I used to display more then 100. I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

One new solution for the old question...

After browsing whole stackOverFlow my colleague saved my day when he mentioned estimatedHeightForRow... After implementing this code the scrolling methods in my tableView worked properly.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:section];
}
```